# error: type `&[str]` does not implement any method in scope named `encode`

Tags: json, rust

I'm trying to write some Rust with a JSON interface.

I'd like the following struct to automatically encode/decode from JSON:

```
#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct Joined<'a> {
    channel: &'a str,
    user: &'a str,
    users: &'a [str],
}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
  "channel":"foo",
  "user":"bar",
  "users":[
    "bar",
    "baz",
    "quux"
  ]
}
```

The error I get is:

```
src/chat.rs:28:5: 28:21 error: type `&[str]` does not implement any method in scope named `encode`
src/chat.rs:28     users: &'a [str],
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/chat.rs:24:12: 24:21 note: in expansion of #[deriving(Encodable)]
src/chat.rs:28:5: 28:21 note: expansion site
```

Is what I'm attempting possible in Rust, or have I misunderstood the nature of `Encodable`?

Comment: Use `String` for struct fields unless you have a really good reason to use a slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&[str]` is a quite peculiar type, and while it compiles, you probably won't be able to do anything with it : most string manipulation functions are implemented for `&str`, not `str` which is a type you would probably never use.

What you meant was probably `users: &'a [&'a str]`, wasn't it ?

Yet, such a struct won't ever be decodable. If you want it to be so, it needs to own its content and thus use `String` instead of `&str` and `Vec<>` instead of `&[]`, like this :

```
#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable)]
struct Joined {
    channel: String,
    user: String,
    users: Vec<String>,
}
```

Comment: I notice that you've not used `&`s in the member types.  Will the `users` field *contain* the vector, or just a reference to it?

Comment: @chrisdew, yes, this is the point. There are no references (`&`) here, so yes, `users` will contain the vector.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Does this mean that the `Joined` struct no longer has a fixed size, as it now contains the contents of the Vector?  Is this a problem?

Comment: @chrisdew Vec is a fixed-size type which handles it's contents internally on the heap. Your `Joined` struct remains fixed-size, there is no problem about that.

Comment: @chrisdew, no. The struct contains the vector, but not its elements. The vector itself is only three pointer-sized values long.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an answer, but I'm not sure it's good (I'm new to Rust).

```
#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct Joined<'a> {
    channel: &'a str,
    user: &'a str,
    users: &'a Vec<&'a str>,
}

...

fn main() {
    let users = vec!["bar","baz","quux"];
    let joined = Joined{channel:"foo",user:"bar",users:&users};
    println!("{}", json::encode(&joined));

...
```

Criticism is very welcome.

---

This works too: (as per @Levans answer)

```
#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct Joined {
    channel: String,
    user: String,
    users: Vec<String>,
}

...

fn main() {
    let users = vec!["bar".to_string(),"baz".to_string(),"quux".to_string()];
    let joined = Joined{channel:"foo".to_string(),user:"bar".to_string(),users:users};
    println!("{}", json::encode(&joined));

...
```

I *think* the difference is that the first is good if you are keeping the source JSON string in memory (as it can just be indexed into), but the second does lots of heap allocations (but lets the original JSON string be freed).

Comment: Actually, if you try to *decode* JSON (with `#[deriving(Decodable)]`), your first version won't work : `&str` does not implement decodable because the objects created by `decode()` *must* be self-owned.